# HTTP Response Connection Keep Alive is dropped

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, http-headers, cisco

I am working on to integrate with Cisco Call Control API (CURRI).

One of the requirement is they will send me a blank request with Connection Keep Alive header request, and I must response with Connection Keep Alive in the header response.

I have created ashx handler which handles the request.

```
Public Class Curri
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        context.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
        context.Response.AddHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout = 20000 max = 1000")

    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

As you can see I have added Connection Keep Alive specifically to the Response Header.

However, when I looked at in Fiddler the Connection Keep Alive is dropped from the Response (missing). Interestingly, the Keep Alive timeout and max was included in the response.

I have checked my IIS and yes HTTP Keep Alive is On.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that even though I did not send "Connection: Keep-Alive" in response it still would work.

So, for anyone working on CURRI don't get too distracted that "Connection: Keep-Alive" is missing.

Just make sure 2 things:

> - Set Response.BufferOutput to False to send "TransferEncoding: chunked"
> - Reboot CISCO box if you think everything is okay, but still doesn't
>     work

Also look at how to set ReverseProxy in Fiddler to help you monitor the HTTP Request/Response